# Animation Render Stuck at 0%

Tags: rendering

When rendering my first animation, Blender gets stuck at zero percent.

I'm trying to render a bunch of separate frames and as soon as I click Animation at the top the bar it says 0 % and I waited about 4 hours and it remains at 0%. So then I tried just clicking render but the same happened to it just as well. Thank you please help

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange! We'll need a bit more info before we can really say what's going on here. Are you rendering straight to an animation file, or are you rendering to a bunch of separate frames? How long have you waited once it gets "stuck"? An animation can be a pretty big task to render. Especially if you try rendering straight to a movie file. If you render a single frame (just an image) does that work?

Comment: Just a heads up as well, it's best to title your question in a way that tells people what your question is about. Something like "Animation Render Stuck at 0%" would let us know what issue your having even before opening the question. You'll have a much higher chance of getting an answer that way.

Comment: Is it possible you could [upload your .blend](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/658/599)?

Comment: Open up a new .blend and only select the file type as FFMpeg video and set the output path. Check that renders correctly. Then try adding settings from your problematic .blend scene.